# Stop UIWebView from restoring URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

My app has a UIWebView added in some view controller in Storyboard. This web view is used to log in to a social network as a mean of alternative sign up / log in. Long story short, when the user signs up into the up and granted access to the main view after successful sign up and log out of the app again, if the user reenters to the web view to log in, the web view remembers the last url loaded inside the web view and re-grants the user access again automatically. How can i stop the web view from caching the url? i read in the documentation that there is something used called state restoration. Web views uses that to restore user's activity in views. is there a way to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do something like this :

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache]removeAllCachedResponses]
```

This should clear your URL cache

Comment: ok thanks. but i'm using caching in my app does it affect it ? mainly subclass of NSCache